# Joomla override com_users/login component

Tags: authentication, joomla, overriding

i have override com_users/login joomla component from control panel.

Now, in html folder i have com_users/login/default.php which is a template file of login component, right?

How can crete my personal controller in html/com_users/?

Comment: I think, you are using latest Joomla 3.5, do you? You can only overwrite the views of the components inside your template. As I know, you can't overwrite the controller. But: What do you want to do?

Comment: Yes, i use 3.5 version. I have to manager programmatically login and registration. When an user login or register i have to do some operation in my database

Comment: How Can do this? I have to create a new component ?

Comment: IMHO I would create a user plugin in joomla. Inside the plugin, you can manipulate some data, but be careful with e.g. manipulating any tables which are using assets, then you have to use JTable class. Otherwise e.g. manipulating the content table, the assets table become corrupt. You can find some examples for user plugins on Joomla site.

Comment: See: https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User

Comment: Ok but, how i can get the post data of registration form inside a plugin?

Comment: What do you want to do with your registration? - maybe there are some other simple solutions.

Comment: In my custom form i have to save other registration information of user in some custom DB tables. I can get data form inside a plugin?

Comment: Yes, within the plugin you'll get the data inside the specific events. Did you ever have used the plugin https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin ? - With this profile, you can add some special fields etc. or you can copy this profile and make your own profile.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I need to study this solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding some user fields to the registration, you can use (enable) the plugin profile.
See: https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin
You can also write your own user plugin, using events:
https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User